# Why do I get this error message "could not find function "patterns" when using the "melt" function in data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table, reshape, reshape2

I am using the data.table (version 1.10.4) to clean data (btw, I have installed "reshape2"), but I got this message:

> Error in melt_check(data, id.vars, measure.vars, variable.name, value.name) : 
>     could not find function "patterns"

I checked many times, but don't figure out why. I am posting my code below, can anyone have a look at it, and tell me where I was wrong? Thanks.

```
library(reshape2)
library(data.table)
library(readxl)
data<-read_excel("Time3Ratee.xlsx")
meltdata<-melt(data,id = 1:4, measure = patterns ("^ratee\\d+$","^RICB.peer\\d+\\.1", "^RICB.peer\\d+\\.2","^RICB.peer\\d+\\.3", "^TICB.peer\\d+\\.1", "^TICB.peer\\d+\\.2","^TICB.peer\\d+\\.3","^LE.peer\\d+\\.1", "^LE.peer\\d+\\.2","^LE.peer\\d+\\.3","^LE.peer\\d+\\.4", "^DEV.peer\\d+\\.1", "^DEV.peer\\d+\\.2","^DEV.peer\\d+\\.3"), value.name = c("ratee", "RICB.peer.1", "RICB.peer.2","RICB.peer.3", "TICB.peer.1", "TICB.peer.2","TICB.peer.3", "LE.peer.1", "LE.peer.2","LE.peer.3","LE.peer.4", "DEV.peer.1", "DEV.peer.2","DEV.peer.3"))
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: `patterns` is a function only supported inside data.table::melt, not reshape2::melt. You'll get the former if you are applying melt to a data.table; but with a data.frame, a matrix or whatever read_excel returns, you'll get the latter.

Comment: @Frank, Could you explain a little bit more about the data.table is the sentence of "You'll get the former if you are applying melt to a data.table"? Do you mean that I should use 'read.table' command to read the data file?

Comment: No, go ahead and use `read_excel`, but then (assuming it gives you a data.frame), use `setDT` before applying `melt`. Like `data <- setDT(read_excel(...))`. Your example is not reproducible, so there is no way for me to test if this works, of course.

Comment: @Frank, it works!!!!Thanks a ton. I'll go to check setDT command later.

Answer (score 3):

(Converting @Franks comment to an answer)

In order to be able to use `data.table::melt`, you need to convert your data set into a `data.table` class by either using using `as.data.table()` or `setDT()`

```
setDT(data)
```

Otherwise, `melt` will default to `reshape2::melt`  and you won't be able to use data.tables functionality such as `patterns`.